# Class file for javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest not found, "cannot access HttpServletRequest"

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload, servletcontextlistener

The code below is for servlet file-upload, I got it from a servlet tutorial but when I try to compile it, this error is thrown ->

```
UploadServlet.java:28: error: cannot access HttpServletRequest
        isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(req);
                                       ^
  class file for javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest not found
UploadServlet.java:49: error: no suitable method found for parseRequest(jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
            List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(req);
                                   ^
    method FileUploadBase.parseRequest(RequestContext) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest cannot be converted to RequestContext)
    method ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest cannot be converted to javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2 errors
```

---

---

```
package fileUpload;

import jakarta.servlet.*;
import jakarta.servlet.http.*;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.*;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private boolean isMultipart;
    private String filePath;
    private int maxFileSize=50 * 1024;
    private int maxMemSize = 4 * 1024;
    private File file;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
         filePath = getServletContext().getInitParameter("file-upload");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(req);
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        if (!isMultipart){
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet Upload</title>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<p> No file Uploaded. </p>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("</html>");
            return;
        }
        DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        factory.setSizeThreshold(maxMemSize);
        factory.setRepository(new File("/user/temp"));
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        upload.setSizeMax(maxFileSize);

        try {
            List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(req);
            Iterator i = fileItems.iterator();

            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet Upload</title>");
            out.println("<body>");

            while (i.hasNext()){
                FileItem fi = (FileItem) i.next();
                if (!fi.isFormField()){
                    String fieldName = fi.getFieldName();
                    String fileName = fi.getName();
                    String contentType = fi.getContentType();
                    boolean isInMemory = fi.isInMemory();
                    long sizeInByte = fi.getSize();

                    if (fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") >= 0){
                        file = new File(filePath + fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")));
                    }else {
                        file = new File(filePath + fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1));
                    }
                    fi.write(file);
                    out.println("Uplaoded FileName "+ fileName+"<br/>");
                }
            }
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
        catch (FileUploadException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        throw new ServletException("Get method used with "+getClass().getName()+": POST method required.");
    }
}
```

I have added all the following jar files in the classpath

1. commons-fileupload-1.4.jar
2. commons-io-2.11.0.jar
3. jsp-api.jar
4. servlet-api.jar

I have also tried a different example from a different tutorial but still I got the same error. I have did all I can in four days but still I have failed.
Please, may someone help me.

Comment: You are probably missing a dependency of one of those jars. Does your tutorial use a build tool like maven or gradle? If not, it might be good to find one that does... otherwise you will have to look at each of those projects and determine which other jars you need to add. That being said I would think that missing class would be in the servlet-api.jar file - generally it's in the `javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:<version>` artifact.

Comment: You're right. I have added ( javax.servlet-3.0.jar ) and replaced jakarta with javax and every thing is working fine. And I'm going to follow your advice of using a build tool. Thank you very much.